# Class returning the extended class' parameter instead of it's own parameter when using an extended method

Tags: java, object, oop, inheritance, extends

Sorry if the title is a little bit confusing! I got this class called Flower that extends a Plant class (for a school assignment) and I have a `getType()` method in Plant which just returns `this.type` . My issue is that when I run this method on a Flower object, instead of returning the type of Flower, it just returns `null` (which is the default return in the Plant class). I was wondering if there is any way to fix this without having to override the method, because that would kind of defeat the whole point of the assignment. The code I have is as below:

Plant Class:

```
public class Plant {
    
    protected List<String> plot = new ArrayList<>();
    private String type;
    
    public Plant() {
        //Some stuff here

        this.type = null;
    }
    
    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
    //More stuff for the class here
```

Flower Class:

```
public class Flower extends Plant {
    private String type;
    private int size;

    public Flower(String type) {
        this.plot = new ArrayList<>();
        this.type = type;
        this.size = 0;

        //More code not important for the question goes here...
```

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Why do you have `private String type;` in `Flower` ?

Comment: You're looking for _shadowing_.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the `private String type;` from the Flower class.

What is happening is your child class (`Flower`) declares a String 'type' and it is hiding the Plant's 'type' field.

Think of it like this - a child can see a parents fields, but a parent can't see a child's fields.

So, when you set `type` in `Flower` it is not available for `Plant` - if you do not declare `type` in Flower, when you set it in `Flower` it will be visible to `Plant`, since that's where it's declared.

Comment: This isn't enough, since `type` is `private` in `Plant`. It should also be changed to `protected` in order to be set in the constructor for `Flower`. Even better: the constructor for `Plant` should take a `type` parameter and set the field to that value, rather than defaulting to `null`. Then the constructor for `Flower` will have to call `super(type)` as the first line, instead of setting `this.type` itself. This allows `type` to remain `private` in `Plant`, and could even be declared `final`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is, that your `Plant` class and your `Flower` class each have their own `type`. And since you don't [override](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/override.html) the `getType()` method in your `Flower` class the return value will always be the `type` of `Plant` which is `null`.

You have some options to solve that problem. Either you do the same thing you did with `plot` where you make the field `protected` and assign it in the constructor of `Flower`.

```java
public class Plant {
    protected List<String> plot;
    protected String type;

    public Plant() {
        this.plot = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

public class Flower extends Plant {
    private int size;

    public Flower(String type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.size = 0;
    }
}
```

Or since every `Plant` has a `type` you could use the "cleaner" version, where you use [super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) to let `Plant` handle the assignment.

```java
public class Plant {
    protected String type;
    protected List<String> plot;

    public Plant(String type) {
        this.type = type;
        this.plot = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getType() {
        return this.type;
    }
}

public class Flower extends Plant {
    private int size;

    public Flower(String type) {
        super(type);
        this.size = 0;
    }
}
```